# Accessing shared folders without logon?

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-shares

How can I access a shared folder on a just booted Windows 2003 Server from a client computer without logging on to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the permissions on your share so that Everyone can access it and set the right write/read permissions.

Comment: This method also works if I set permissions only for myself?

Comment: Windows Home Server works best if you create the folders in the management tool it provides, it will then set the appropriate permissions etc.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you're logged in or not on the server. Connect like you normally would. File sharing runs as a service, so it doesn't matter whether or not the server is logged in.